# i want to know if there is any extra tasks to be done after completing the closed test with 20 testers for atleast 14 days

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

According to playstore new policy , i want to know if there is any extra tasks to be done after completing the closed test with  20 testers for atleast 14 days. after completing this can i move my app to production? or any other testing need to be done. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can promote it to production after that

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can just promote it to production or add a new release once you got the production. For those who need 20 testers can follow the below way ,

I have created this app called Testers Community to solve the problem of 20 testers for 14 days. You can download the app here

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.testerscommunity

What is Testers Community ?
We are a Community anyone can join. Here instead of paying 20-100 bucks for testers we just test our apps among ourselves. We ensure everyone get 20 testers for Free.